# Angular Js Calling function from HTML with 'this' keyword yields unexpected result

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an object in html like this:

```
<textarea id="bragInputText" type="text"
        class="form-control margin-bottom" ng-model="message"
        ng-controller='loadController' ng-init='expandTextarea(this)'
        required>
</textarea>
```

This call the following function when it is loaded:

```
app.controller('loadController', function($scope){
    $scope.expandTextarea = function (textarea) {
         console.log(textarea.SOMEPROPERTY);
    }
});
```

Some Property refers to a common attribute of a html object.  textarea.scrollHeight for example. However when I test the code, it logs undefined. That means that the parameter generated from 'this' is not what i expected. What is the parameter referring to in this case? And how can I access the HTML object with this function without using getElementById?

Comment: You should not be manipulating the DOM inside the controller

Comment: create a directive. dom manupulation is task of directives not controllers

Comment: isnt ng-init a directive? Could you give me an example?

Comment: You need a custom directive within which the element itself is exposed. Lots of tutorials around on how to create a simple directive like this